# OpenWeather get method

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

This is my code, i print the address, and when I enter address from NSLOG in browser, it shows desired data, but in my code, there is error.

```
+(void)getCityInformationByCityName:(NSString *)namer
                       successBlock:(void (^)(NSDictionary *response))successHandler
                         errorBlock:(void (^) (NSDictionary *error))errorHandler
{
    NSString *apiKey = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"apiKey"];

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=%@&APPID=%@", namer, apiKey];
    NSLog(@"%@", url);
    [manager GET:url parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        successHandler(responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSDictionary *userInfo = [error userInfo];
        errorHandler(userInfo);
    }];
}
```

**SOLVED: Replaced api, with https://**

Comment: your problem is solved or not bro

Comment: Solved. Problem was in link, I replaced api with https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED: Replaced api, with https://**